# How I make jQuery parse to have a valid json?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have an issue with jquery/ajax script. Here  I am using PHP as serverside and below is my php code.

```
$tabData = 
<<<HTML
<div class="table-responsive-md">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      $thead
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      $tbody
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
HTML;

$jsonData = ['success'=>true
            ,'showFlag'=>false
            ,'tabData'=> $tabData    
            ];     
echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

My jquery/ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: {'tab':datatab}, 
  beforeSend: function() {
    $loader.removeClass('d-none');
  },
  success: function(json) {
    json = jQuery.parseJSON(json);          
    if (json.success) {
      $wrapper.html(json.tabData);
      $this.tab('show');
      return false;
    } 
  },
  complete: function(){
    $loader.removeClass('d-block');
  } 
})
```

This ajax request/response works properly in firefox but not in chrome. In chrome browser, there is an error like this `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<div class"... is not valid JSON`.
and response tab in browser inspector I can see a message like this `Failed to load response data: request content was evicted from inspector cache`.

This is I use to load bootstrap tabs and this code is for one tab of it. In other tabs, I use same json format in php to get data into tab and it is working without problem. This problem has only for one tab.

Hope somebody may help me out figure this out.

Comment: just replace <<<HTML  / HTML;   with single quote ('); this should work

Comment: 1. Add the correct header to the PHP of `Content-type: application/json` 2. remove the `json = jQuery.parseJSON(json);` and try again. It is NOT recommended to use JSON to send HTML via AJAX when you can just send HTML. Alternatively why send HTML when you can send JSON and assemble the table on the client?

Comment: @Klayser inside single quotes, the variables contained in that string will not be parsed.

Comment: @mplungjan, You mean, do I need to add `Content-type: application/json` inside jquery.ajax() ? I tried it like that but Its not working.. As you mentioned, HTML is the most suitable in this case. my `$jsonData` array have few more data to send to the js. Thats why I use `json` here. But I would like to know most corrected way to do this.

Comment: Add the correct header to the ***PHP*** of `header("Content-type: application/json");` !

Comment: And the recommended method is to send ONLY the data and then on the client you can parse the data easily into a table element, which can even be a template

Comment: your html from $tabData variable is malformed. It should start with <HTML>... and ends with </HTML>. That's why you're getting this unexpected token '<' error

Comment: @Sergio, Haven't you heard php [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax?